# What is Difference Between Below Two Line Of Codes

Tags: c#

i am not able to understand why we have to add `"a"+randomtext.Next(0,26)` for text

```
buffer[i] = (char)('a' + random.Next(0, 26));
```

versus

```
buffer[i] = (char)( random.Next(0, 26));
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question as it is not very clear? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Adding 'a' just means your character will fall in the range of a-z, since the lower case alphabet starts with "a = 97", not zero.

Comment: _"why we have to add "a"+randomtext.Next(0,26) for text"_ -- lacking any other context, you _don't_ have to add `'a'`. You've gotten some reasonable feedback as to why one _might_, but there's nothing in your question that indicates it's required, so it's also not possible to answer a question asking why it might be required. And unfortunately, all three answers conflate ASCII with the C# `char` type, which actually stores UTF16 encodings, _not_ ASCII (not coincidentally, `'a'` in UTF16 has the same numeric value as `'a'` in ASCII, but that doesn't mean sloppy explanations are okay).

Comment: "_i am not able to understand why we have to add "a"+randomtext.Next(0,26) for text_". Well, what could possibly stop you from trying your program once without using `'a' + ...` and once with using `'a' + ...`. There, you just found yourself an answer to your question... ;-)

Comment: Please improve the question. You've gotten some approximate answers. However, those that refer to an "alphabet" must be referring to the [ISO Basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet) alphabet, which is used in English. Also note that since [`char`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netframework-4.8) is a UTF-16 code unit (UTF-16 is a character encoding for the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set), those that refer to ASCII are only doing so for pedagogical reasons and are technically incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is so you have all the letters of the alphabet.

When you pick a number between 0 and 25 and convert it to a char, you will end up with all kind of symbols in the [ASCII-Table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

So you add the 'a' which is treated like an int (value is 97) to actually start at the correct position in the ascii-table.

So lets say you random 4.

This line

```
(char)('a' + random.Next(0, 26));
```

will be

```
(char) ('a' + 4)
(char) (97 + 4)
(char) (101) => e
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't add 'a', you create an unprintable character.
Value of 'a' + random value gives you a printable character

You can look ASCII values at this link : http://www.asciitable.com/mobile/

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII text encoding uses the lower 7 bits of a byte to encode characters. Not all of those characters are visible/printable (such as space, tab, newline, end-of-text, end-of-transmission, etc.).

Lower case letters are encoded as values 0x61 ('a') through 0x7a ('z'). By adding 'a' to your random value you guarantee that you will get one of the lower-case letters. Otherwise you would only get non-printable characters.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there are issues with this code re 118n but ignoring that for now …

The simple answer to why 'a' was added is to change the range of values placed into the buffer.

The same result may have been accomplished by simply adjusting the two values in the call to random.Next(97,123) etc. but in the interest of making the code understandable, adding the 'a' makes it more obvious what the acceptable range of values was that the coder intended to add to the buffer.